# Wordpress Theme admin panel showing fatal error in local server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a project in WordPress.
Here we use theme `jupiter`. When I set up it on my local XAMPP server, its theme option is not working.
This problem is with my PC, but it working on another PC.
My **XAMPP is latest version**.

The error it showing :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php:80 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php(9): mkOptionGenerator->render() #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-content\themes\jupiter\functions.php(260): mkOptionGenerator->__construct('Jupiter_options', Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-includes\plugin.php(503): Theme->_load_option_page('') #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-admin\admin.php(236): do_action('toplevel_page_m...') #4 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\devatom\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php on line 80
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation@ Amd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. i found that an `array` is used as `function name` in the file

Answer (score 5):

Open file jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php on line 80

Find below code

```
$this->$option['type']( $option );
```

and replace with

```
$this->{$option['type']}( $option );
```

Your issue will resolve .
thanks

Comment: This is the correct answer. This problem is created on PHP 7 because in PHP 7 there is some change in the Syntax.
Thanks