# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in:..wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php:80

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

I developed a theme for my woocommerce store locally through jupitor wordpress them, xampp. Now I have installed wordpress on a server, and integrated the theme I developed. I get this error when i open theme option page:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
> Function name must be a string in
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php:80
>
> Stack trace: #0
>
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php(9):
> mkOptionGenerator->render() #1
>
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-content\themes\jupiter\functions.php(253):
>
> mkOptionGenerator->__construct('Jupiter_options', Array) #2
>
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-includes\plugin.php(524):
>
> Theme->_load_option_page('') #3
>
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-admin\admin.php(222):
>
> do_action('toplevel_page_m...') #4 {main} thrown in
> H:\root\home\amanantru3-001\www\mydesign\wp-content\themes\jupiter\framework\admin\generators\option-generator.php
> on line 80

Also, my visual composer is not working on the server now.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that an array is used as function name in the file.

You can check the same error reported here:

[Wordpress Theme admin panel showing fatal error in local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759360/wordpress-theme-admin-panel-showing-fatal-error-in-local-server)

Comment: Hi, thanks but i am new in WP. will you please tell me how to check an array used by function name?

Comment: you check above files for that.